Three day problem: Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'
I study computer engineering and one of my assignments for the semester is to create an app, with react native, so I'm new to this area, I've been studying for about 3 days (so be kind, and if you need for more information, just ask and I will send it). I've been having a problem for a few days now and I can't solve it in any way, I hope you can help me
Context: I'm trying to use a different font in my project, I tried the most native way possible, creating the fonts file within assets, using expo-font and adding its path to the app.json file, when using the npx expo start command and the warning "not a system font" opened in expo go and it was not loaded. Then I discovered that I needed to give npx expo prebuild and then npx expo run:android
But I didn't have an Android emulator, so I downloaded Android Studio, and that's where my biggest problem began. I can create a project normally in Android Studio, I can even open the emulator normally, but when I use run:android I get this error error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using C:\Users\Public\FaculdadeTrabalhos\ViaSeguraTeste2\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [prefab] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17\\bin\\java" ^
        --class-path ^
        "C:\\Users\\kawÒ\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.google.prefab\\cli\\2.0.0\\f2702b5ca13df54e3ca92f29d6b403fb6285d8df\\cli-2.0.0-all.jar"

See the complete error here: https://pastebin.com/Xr0nw3Ad
Additional info
JDK: 17
Gradle: 8.7 (I downloaded it from the website and created the directory: "C:Gradle" and extracted the files inside)
Node: 21.7.1
Windows 10
Using Visual Studio
Environment variables:
ANDROID_HOME= C:\Users\Public\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
PATH:

C:\Users\Public\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Gradle\gradle-8.7\bin
C:\Users\Public\Android\Sdk\emulator
C:\Users\Public\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
C:\Users\Public\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Users\Public\Android\Sdk\tools
7.C:\Gradle\gradle-8.7

expo-doctor
(node:4668) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
WARNING: We recommend using PowerShell or Bash via WSL 2 for development with Expo CLI on Windows. You may encounter issues using cmd.exe.
✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check native tooling versions
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check for issues with metro config
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK
✔ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK


Can you post the output of npx expo-doctor?

@MichaelBahl, I updated the post with npx expo-doctor

Why you don‘t load the font at runtime ?

@MichaelBahl, when I try this way, it doesn't leave the SplashScreen, even without an error in the console, look this https://pastebin.com/i7DpWCFz

Here is an working example:

import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import {  useCallback } from 'react';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
function Login() {
  const nav = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      }}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          nav.navigate('Welcome');
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30 }}>Red</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}
function Singup() {
  const nav = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
      }}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          nav.navigate('Login');
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30 }}>Green</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}

function Welcome() {
  const nav = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
      }}>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          nav.navigate('Signup');
        }}>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30 }}>Orange</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function AppNav() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Welcome">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Welcome"
          component={Welcome}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Signup"
          component={Singup}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);

  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <AppNav />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});


